# How to dynamically create database driven select field with php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make an invoice script with PHP+MySQL. I made my Invoice Entry Screen. Everything working perfectly. I also added "Add New Line" button.

Here is the problem, when I clicked the "Add New Line" all functions which used on first line are disabled. I do not have enough knowledge on JS.

Here are the Codes:

**PHP:**

```
<div class="table-striped" id="dataTable">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Product No</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Amount</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="ekleaq">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="No" id="no1" class="form-control" name="no1[]" required=""></td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="col-xs selectContainer">
                    <select name="productno1[]" class="form-control" id="Bname" onchange="ShowData(this.options[this.selectedIndex])">
                        <?php
                            while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
                                unset($id, $name, $ax1, $ax2);
                                $id = $row['inv_products_id'];
                                $name = $row['inv_products_no'];
                                $ax1 = $row['inv_products_desc'];
                                $ax2 = $row['inv_products_price'];
                                echo '<option value="'.$id.'" data-ax1="'.$ax1.'" data-ax2="'.$ax2.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Decription" id="decription1" class="form-control" name="decription1[]" required=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Price" id="price1" class="form-control" name="price1[]" required=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" id="quantity1" class="form-control" name="quantity1[]" required="" onchange="CalculateData()"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Amount" id="amount1" class="form-control" name="amount1[]"></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton" id="ekle"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
$("#ekle").click(function(){
    $("#ekleaq")
      .append('<tr><td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="No" id="no1" class="form-control" name="no1[]" required=""></td><td> \
    <div class="col-xs selectContainer"><select name="productno1[]" class="form-control" id="Bname" onchange="ShowData(this.options[this.selectedIndex])"> "<?php while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){ unset($id, $name, $ax1, $ax2);$id = $row['inv_products_id'];$name = $row['inv_products_no'];$ax1 = $row['inv_products_desc'];$ax2 = $row['inv_products_price'];echo '<option value="'.$id.'" data-ax1="'.$ax1.'" data-ax2="'.$ax2.'">'.$name.'</option>'; } ?>" </select> \
                                        </div></td><td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Decription" id="decription1" class="form-control" name="decription1[]" required=""></td><td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Price" id="price1" class="form-control" name="price1[]" required=""></td><td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Quantity" id="quantity1" class="form-control" name="quantity1[]" required="" onchange="CalculateData()"></td><td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Amount" id="amount1" class="form-control" name="amount1[]"></td></tr>');
});

function ShowData(obj)
{
    document.getElementById('decription1').value = obj.getAttribute('data-ax1');
    document.getElementById('price1').value = obj.getAttribute('data-ax2');
}

function CalculateData(input)
{
    price = document.getElementById('price1');
    quantity = document.getElementById('quantity1');
    amount1.value = price.value * quantity.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `"all functions which used on first line are disabled"` - What does that even mean?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: This means obviously that `ShowData` is not working for a dynamically added element.

Comment: And I advise you to open developers console and see syntax errors.

Comment: @u_mulder - obvious to us what the problem is, yes - but clearly not obvious to the OP.